# Vue Js 2 include CSS into main index.html

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I am developing an app first time with VueJS 2 + Webpack
And I have created a style.css file that I want to include globaly into index.html file in the root of my app

I have tried loading it from different folders (src, src/assets, root, src, components, node_modules) but as a result i always get 404 error for the specific file.

I have also  tried all sorts of paths ../src , /src..., ./src... makes no difference..

What is the correct way to include a style.css file into your project?
Where it should be located ? And how should I call it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured out that local css file can be accessed by the main index.html file if it is located in "static" folder of the VueJs project

then just add to the `<head>` section of your index.html file `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='static/bootstrap.css'>` and you are done.